# Proving if $F$ is defined on a connected set $D$, $F(D)$ is connected, assuming f is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So the book tried a proof by contradiction,
Assumed that F(D) is not connected. And This meant

let $A$ and $B$ be two mutually separated sets, Assume $A\cup B=F(D)$ so that $F(D)$ is not connected.

It's true by far, but then the book goes further and assumes that $A$ and $B$ are open relative to $F(D)$. How come?

Couldnt $A$ and $B$ be closed but they have a $dist(A,B)>0$ that would make then mutually separated.

I believe $A$ and $B$ being closed and having a $dist(A,B)>0$ wouldn't contradict with f being continuous right? Would contradict with $D$ being connected however, and we could prove $F(D)$ is connected from this way too.

But that wouldn't give us the exact prove we also have the take into the case where they are open sets as the book suggests. But book didn't even care about this step, Is the book wrong or am I?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are both open and closed relative to $F(D)$

Comment: Well, isn't that the definition of non-connectedness? Being a disjoint union of two nonempty *open* subsets.

Comment: What is the relationship between the continuous function $f$ in your title, and $F$?

Comment: You can give several equivalent conditions for connectedness that are easily proved to be equivalent (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). One other says a space $X$ is connected if the only closed and (at the same time) open (clopen) subset are trivial (i.e. $X$ itself and $\emptyset$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected. The setting is quite general.

Assume $X$ is a connected topological space, $Y$ a topological space, $f\colon X\to Y$ a continuous function (this means that the pre-image of every open set in $Y$ is open in $X$). Then $f(X)$ is connected in $Y$ (w.r.t. the induced topology).

By contradiction, assume $f(X)$ disconnected. Then, there exist $A,B\subseteq f(X)$ disjoint and clopen (i.e., both closed and open) in the induced topology s.t. $f(X)=A\cup B$. Consider now the pre-images $f^{-1}(A),f^{-1}(B)\subseteq X$: these are disjoint (since $A,B$ are) and both clopen (they are both open, since $f$ is continuous; the complementary of the one is the other). Now, $X=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$, yielding that $X$ is disconnected, too. Contradiction.